# Impedir que animação repita ao mudar a orientação do dispositivo

Tags: java, android, android-layout, animação

Estou trabalhando em uma tela que contém uma animação que é repetida toda vez que a tela é girada. Procurei mas não achei nenhuma informação precisa do que preciso fazer para que a animação não se repita ao mudar a orientação do dispositivo.

Esse é o código da Activity em questão:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Login extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        ImageView imgLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        final LinearLayout LoginBox = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LoginBox);

        LoginBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Animation animTranslate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Login.this,
                R.anim.anim_logo);
        animTranslate.setFillAfter(true);
        animTranslate.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                LoginBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Animation animFade = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Login.this,
                        R.anim.anim_login);
                LoginBox.startAnimation(animFade);

            }
        });
        imgLogo.startAnimation(animTranslate);
    }
}
```

Lendo um pouco sobre o ciclo de vida de uma Activity, vi que a mesma é reinciada toda vez que o dispositivo é girado. A dúvida que ficou é: qual código preciso implementar para que a animação não seja repetida?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sempre que a orientação é alterada a sua *Activity* é recriada: o método `onCreate`é chamado.

Uma forma simples de você verificar se a sua *Activity* foi recriada é verificar se o *Bundle* passado ao método `onCreate` é nulo ou não.

Quando a *Activity* é criada pela primeira vez `savedInstanceState` é nulo.

Se você quer que a animação seja apenas executada no arranque da aplicação coloque a instrução `startAnimation` dentro de um `if`:

```
if(savedInstanceState == null){
    imgLogo.startAnimation(animTranslate);
}
```

Se você quiser saber mais sobre como utilizar o *Bundle* passado ao método `onCreate` siga este [Link](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-1/)

Comment: muito obrigado!

Comment: estava testando aqui e percebi que, ao verificar se o Bundle savedInstanceState é nulo, o layout é redefinido para o estado antes da animação (é como se a animação não tivesse sido executada). Saberia me dizer por que isso ocorre?

Comment: Isso ocorre porque a *Activity* é recriada ou seja é como ela nunca tivesse existido. No entanto o Android usa o *Bundle* passado ao método `onCreate` para guardar parte do estado que a *Activity* tinha antes de ser recriada. Você também pode usar esse *Bundle* para guardar o que achar necessário para que, quando a *Activity* for recriada, seja possível colocá-la num estado igual ao anterior, antes da recriação. Daí a razão do link que eu adicionei à resposta.